# ActionListener and dynamic(?) GUI

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I've read through a dozen or so actionlistener/loop related questions here, but I'm not sure I've found my answer. I started on my first large Java project, a text RPG that's spiraled into around 5K lines of logic and game features which was functioning as intended using just the console - when I decided I'd try to build a Java swing GUI for it instead. Here's my problem:

I use a Room object which handles the description of where the player is at and also has an array of options for the player to choose next which it creates dynamically based on what cell the room's id is in on a csv file and what is beside it. I stopped outputting this to the console and instead started creating JButtons based on the options array like so:

```
public void showNarrate(){
       add(dd,gridConstraints);
       optionCopy.clear();
       int i = 0;
       for(JButton j : optionButtons){
       //adding and formatting buttons to gridBagConstraint I also set actionCommand for each button to the triggerValue (ID of the next room which the button should take the player to) 
       }

       //I tried using a copy of my JButton array here so I could have something to iterate over in actionListener after clearing out the original 
       //(Since it needs to be cleared so the next Room's buttons can be built after the player chooses an option) 
       for(JButton j : optionButtons){

           optionCopy.add(j);
       }

       optionButtons.clear();

        //dd is a seperate drawingComponent I used for outputting room descriptions which may be totally unnecessary at this point :/
       dd.repaint();
       setVisible(true);

   }
```

Over in actionlistener (Same class) this is how I tried to swing it:

```
        for(JButton j : optionCopy){
            if(e.getActionCommand().equals(j.getActionCommand())){
                Main.saveRoom = Main.currentRoom;
                Main.currentRoom = j.getActionCommand();


                System.out.println(Main.currentRoom);
            }
        }}
```

Then in my main class I call:
narrator.narrate(currentRoom, saveRoom); which takes care of some other logic concerning locked doors, encounters, etc. 
Also in Main loop are some other methods related to autosave and tracking which rooms the player has visited. I know from other q/a i'v read on here that this is all pretty bad design, and I'm sttarting to understand that now, but my issue is this:

The first room of the game loads up fine, when I click a button it outputs to console(Just for testing) the correct trigger value of the room the button should be calling, so I'm getting that far, but how can I call the same method over again now?

-If I call narrate from actionListener it will wind up calling itself again and complain about ConcurrentModification.

-If I try to keep a loop going in my Main class it will keep looping and won't allow for the player to actually choose a button.

I've never used threads before, which I wonder might be the answer,and the closest thing to a related answer I've found is this: 
[Java: Method wait for ActionListener in another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186265/java-method-wait-for-actionlistener-in-another-class)
but I don't think moving actionListener to Main class would resolve my problem which is actionListener winding up calling itself recursively. And as for the observer-observable pattern... I just can't understand it :(

I appreciate any and all help, I've learned a LOT trying to make this thing work without seeking help as much as possible but this has stumped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop in `actionPerformed` only checks whether a `JButton` exists in your `optionList` with the given actionCommand. However this can be done before actually doing something:

```
boolean contained = false;
for (JButton j : optionButtons)
  if (j.getActionCommand().equals(e.getActionCommand()))
    contained = true;

if (contained) {
  // change room
}
```

now you can call `narrate` because you have finished iterating over the collection beforehand and will not get a `ConcurrentModificationException`